# codeigniter: mongodb library unable to load

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am working with code-igniter in which I want to work with MONGODB at the backend. I used the drivers from https://github.com/huglester/MongoDB-CodeIgniter-Driver ,i.e. added the config (named mongo_db.php) and library files (named Mongo_db.php) as per instructed.

I load this library in the constructor method of my model. Now the issue is that this library class doesn't load and gives me the following error:
"Unable to load the requested class: Mongo_db"

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can't tell it will solve the issue, but remove all closing PHP tags from files.

Comment: I haven't used any! There ain't any.

Comment: There are PHP closing tags in files of your provided link. Check it again.

Comment: I tried debugging! IF IT HELPS..... The error comes from /system/core/loader.php  and the error comes from the part of code where it checks if the class is an extension request.

Comment: yes! I had removed those while copying the code to my CI folder.

Comment: I resolved the error. Turns out, I need to extend my loader class and customize it such that other other users libraries can be loaded. Here's the link to the solution: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Tpojka

Comment: No problem. I am glad you succeeded to solve your issue. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error.

Turns out, I need to extend my loader class and customize it such that other other "users" libraries can be loaded.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers) to the solution